# Change height/width of profile picture from Facebook API user/taggable friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can query Facebook's API to get a list of taggable friends with:

```
FB.api('me/taggable_friends', function (taggable) {
    document.getElementById('friends').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(taggable);
});
```

But this only returns a url to a tiny profile picture. I'd like to get the full sized picture.

[Are non-app users' pictures still avalible in Facebook Open Graph v2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418493/are-non-app-users-pictures-still-avalible-in-facebook-open-graph-v2-0)

The above link has a comment by Simon Cross that says "You can use ...? Fields=width(n),height(n) to get a larger image" but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Does anyone know how this works?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same issue, the Facebook docs on this are awful, but finally I worked it out:

```
    FB.api(
        "/me/taggable_friends?fields=name,picture.width(100), picture.height(100)",
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            // Do what you like with the response data here response.data;
            callback();
          } else {
            console.log(response);
          }

        }
    );
```

Hoe that helps!

Comment: This is no longer working for versions 2.1 and later. You'll get an HTTP Status of 400 if you try it.

Comment: It's working for me in the JavaScript SDK with the following declarations:

FB.api ('/me',  **{ fields: 'name, picture.width(100).height(100)' }**, function(response) { ... } );

Answer (score 13):

The format of @Jozef's answer did not work for me.  This worked instead:

```
fields=name,picture.width(100).height(100)
```

I'm using the nodejs module [facebook-node-sdk](https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk), so perhaps my issue was specific to that.  Here is a full example:

```
   FB.api('me/taggable_friends', {
       fields:         'name,picture.width(100).height(100)',
       limit:          20,
       access_token:   req.session.access_token
   }, function (result) {
       if(!result || result.error) {
           return false;
       }
       d = {
         friends: result.data,
       };

      res.render('myview', d);
   });
```

That will return a limit of 20 friends, with 100x100 px thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks! Ironically on FB docs it is said that: "This endpoint doesn't have any parameters."

Answer (score 2):

In version 2.5 I was not able to set the width and height of a picture however if you make the call like this it will work.

```
me/taggable_friends?fields=picture.width(500).height(500)
```

The image you get back seems to be at least as big as what you ask for, no scaling, but it's better than too small.

Comment: If you don't want to get a cropped picture, just consider using extra large width (something like 5000), then height will be set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for iOS:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"
     parameters:@{@"fields" : @"name,picture.width(500).height(500)"}
     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    /* handle the result */
    if(!error){
        NSArray *friends = result[@"data"];
        // do something with the friends list
    } else{
        // show the error
    }
}];
```